# Single click on swf file is not working for IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-10

I have created a html page with swf object in it. I bind click event for parent div of that object. Click is working in FireFox but in IE10 single click is not working, only double click triggers the click event. Any solution for make single click work on swf object or its parent div in IE10?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a patent related issue. Not an issue from your side. Have a look at this link.

forums.adobe.com/thread/11976